# How can I publish my dataset on Google Dataset Search?

Tags: dataset

I want to put my dataset which I have prepared in Google Dataset Search. I didn't find any procedure to do this task online.

This question - [How can I post my doctoral lab's datasets on Google Dataset Search?](https://support.google.com/webmasters/forum/AAAA2Jdx3sUNtTsJz_7jJY?hl=en) asked in Google support provide answers but the corresponding links are not of great use.
Can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to make your dataset eligible to be included in [Dataset Search](http://g.co/DatasetSearch) results is to upload it to a repository that adheres to metadata standards used by Dataset Search. There are many such repositories. You can try the following:

- https://zenodo.org
- https://figshare.com
- https://dataverse.harvard.edu/
- https://www.kaggle.com/datasets

If you don't want to use an external repository you will need to embed metadata in the webpage you host that describes the datasets. More information on this [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/dataset).